# Can we change textbox properties through javascript validator rules?

Tags: javascript, requiredfieldvalidator

I want to change my text box properties to read-only. I have two values in my list box, local and domain. When I select domain then my next text box field should be set to read-only.
How I can change this property?

> ×
>           Create User
>         
>         
>           
>             
>               
>               
>                 Username:
>                   
>                     
>                   
>                 
>                 
>                   First Name:
>                   
>                     
>                     
>                   
>                 
>                 
>                   Last Name:
>                   
>                     
>                     
>                   
>                 
>                 
>                   Email:
>                   
>                     
>                     
>                   
>                 
>                 
>                   User Type:
>                   
>                     
>                       Local User
>                       Domain User
>                     
>                     
>                   
>                 
>                 
>                   Password:
>                   
>                     
>                     
>                   
>                 
>                 
>                   Re-enter Password:
>                   
>                     
>                   
>                 
>               
>             
>           
>         
>         
>           Cancel
>           Add

Here is my code.

Comment: You do this by setting the "readonly" attribute on the textarea.  If you need more specific information, post some code so we can see what we're working with.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add listener on your select change to be able to modify next input field

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var elem = document.getElementById('our-select')
  
  elem.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    if(event.target.value === 'local'){
      document.getElementById('our-input').disabled = true;
    } else {
      document.getElementById('our-input').disabled = false;
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<select id="our-select">
  <option>domain</option>
  <option>local</option>  
</select>
<input id="our-input" />
```